# Default alpha value from attribute node

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, custom-attributes

I was trying to use the alpha channel as an "exist" factor for a color attribute inside the shader editor and I discovered that the default value for this channel (as default I mean the value it outputs when no valid attribute is selected) is different when the domain type is set to geometry.
Object, Instancer and View Layer outputs black and Geometry outputs white.

[image]

[image]

And this is not because the cube is a geometry, here's a test with cube instances and it works the same:

[image]

[image]

Is there a reason for it to work like that?